# linux directories with same owner&group, on can list files other doesn't

Tags: windows, linux, permissions

I have a share in Linux. I mount that share in Windows by assigning a letter for eg: X:

in that X: I have music and movies folder. Both have admin rights on the owner and group

in Windows. In TwonkyMedia, I can see the files of movies folder, but cannot see the files of music folder.

Files in both the directories have admin owner and group rights.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Do the permissions also match?

Comment: Cannot see them... do you get an error or nothing appears? Maybe the music folder was actually a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at the ownership and permissions of both folders in the share UNDER LINUX to see what they look like.

Try this, and let us know what is reported:

```
$ cd wherever-the-share-is
$ ls -ld movies music 
...if this exists for your version of Linux:
$ getfacl movies music
```

This will help with diagnosing your problem.

Thanks!
-pbr

Answer (score 0):

On the Linux box, change into the music directory and run "chmod -R 777 *" or something similar depending on your distro. This assumes you're on a secure home network or otherwise don't care about file security. If that gets the Windows box to see the files, you can always roll back the chmod level later.

Comment: Recursive chmod is almost NEVER a good idea - here's why: you almost never want the same permissions on both FILES and DIRECTORIES.  -R doesn't account for this.   chmod 777 is likewise almost never a good idea; you're setting the executable bit on a random bunch of files.  Yuck.  ALSO - there's no "rollback" - once you chmod, you can't undo - you have to know what you want as permissions for every single file and directory which you've affected.  One more reason -R is a bad thing.

Comment: I seriously doubt someone wanting to mount music and movies on a Windows box cares, which is why I said "secure home network or otherwise don't care." I also doubt he has or wants his files to have different permission levels - by rollback I mean to 755 and more restrictive, not "historical" rollback.